# How to fix the poor fitting of 1-D data?

Tags: python, distribution, curve-fitting, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have data set (1-D), with only one independent column. I would like to fit any model to it in order to sample from that model.  The raw data
[Data set](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/64d9270f59c500c310069e4eb7eb165220190817223134/8a915e)

I tried various theoretical distributions from Fitter package (here https://pypi.org/project/fitter/), none of them works fine. Then i tried Kernel Density Estimation using sklearn. It is good, but i could not prevent negative values due to the way it works. Finally, i tried log normal, but it is not really perfect.

Code for log normal here

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import math
from sklearn.metrics import  r2_score,mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error

NN = 3915 # sample same number as original data set

df = pd.read_excel (r'Data_sets2.xlsx',sheet_name="Set1")

eps = 0.1  # Additional term for c

"""
    Estimate parameters of log(c) as normal distribution
"""
df["c"] = df["c"] + eps
mu = np.mean(np.log(df["c"]))
s  = np.std(np.log(df["c"]))
print("Mean:",mu,"std:",s)


def simulate(N):
    c = []
    for i in range(N):
        c_s = np.exp(np.random.normal(loc = mu, scale = s, size=1)[0])
        c.append(round(c_s))
    return (c)


predicted_c = simulate(NN)


XX=scipy.arange(3915)
### plot C relation ###
plt.scatter(XX,df["c"],color='g',label="Original data")
plt.scatter(XX,predicted_c,color='r',label="Sample data")
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('c')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

original vs samples

[image: fitted data]

What i am looking for is how to improve the fitting, any suggestions or direction to models that may fit my data with a better accuracy is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical Python fitter for the scipy statistical distribution Double Gamma using your spreadsheet data, I hope this might be of some use as a Normal distribution seems to be a poor fit to this data set. The scipy documentation for dgamma is at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dgamma.html - incidentally,the double Weibull distribution fit almost as well.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Data_sets2.xlsx',sheet_name="Set1")
eps = 0.1  # Additional term for c

data = df["c"] + eps

P = ss.dgamma.fit(data)
rX = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 50)
rP = ss.dgamma.pdf(rX, *P)

plt.hist(data,bins=25, normed=True, color='slategrey')

plt.plot(rX, rP, color='darkturquoise')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks,, but how to get dgamma parameters in order to sample using rvs? also, would be possible to control min value to be 0, in order to avoid negative values?

Comment: Also, is there a way to assess its accuracy, rather than visual inspection? Thanks

Comment: The Burr distribution: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.burr.html is non-negative and fits very nearly as well as the double gamma, just replace all code instances of "ss.dgamma" with ss.burr". As for a fit statistic to assess fitting accuracy, I personally use the scipy.stats nnlf function for continuous distributions as in "distribution.nnlf(fitted_parameters, data)"

Comment: Thanks James,, i tried to sample with burr like r = ss.burr.rvs(P[0],P[1], size=1000000),, min is good, but max can go very big.. is there a way to control max value?. What about fitting log values instead of the values as i did before?

Comment: for nnlf, i tried ss.burr.nnlf(P,c), it returns 11698.. but cannot really tell more about it,, the documentation is very poor about it, even an example is not included here http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.nnlf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.nnlf

Comment: Documentation for nnlf: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.nnlf.html - I do not know of a way to control the maximum value other than using a programmatic limit (clipping).